# The Volume of A Hyperboloid in Minkowski Spacetime

Tags: homework-and-exercises, special-relativity

The equation of for a hyperboloid is given by
$$-t^{2}+x^{2}+y^{2}=1$$
where $\left\{t,x,y\right\}$ is the Cartesian coordinate of the 2+1 dimensional Minkowski spacetime. Its metric in this coordinate is given by
$$ds^{2}=-dt^{2}+dx^{2}+dy^{2}$$
Now I want to calculate the volume of the hyperboloid given above.

I am confused by this exercise because if we do a wick rotation into Euclidean signature, the volume is just $4\pi$, the area of a unit sphere. However, in Euclidean space, the area of a hyperboloid is divergent. My guess is that the area of the hyperbolic in Lorentzian signature is finite and is still $4\pi$.

Is that correct?

Comment: Please note that this site is not a place to obtain solutions to worked problems. Please see [this Meta post on asking homework-like questions](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/714/25301) and [this Meta post for "check my work problems"](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6093/25301).

Comment: @KyleKanos Whether my intention was to obtain solutions is very subjective. This random question came in my mind during my research project. I posted it as an homework exercise because it is very easy. I certainty know the rules of this website and have no intention to break it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first statement was correct, the volume of the hyperboloid should be infinite in Minkowski space if the same GR volume element is used to describe the volume.

Wick rotation is a "mathematical" trick that physicists like using for finding solutions to certain types of problems, but it doesn't always work in the way you expect it to work. Essentially what the Wick rotation is, is merely a statement of analytic continuation for certain functions (for example Gaussian integrals). For example, the following formula

$$\int\limits^{\infty}_{-\infty}e^{-ax^2+bx}=\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{a}}e^{\frac{b^2}{4a}}$$

just so happens to converge for all complex $a,b\in \mathbb{C}, Re(a)>0$. Then physicists take advantage of this analyticity property (or postulate it even sometimes) to compute the integral or associated physical quantities in the region where it's easiest to do so (eg. the real axis) and then analytically continue to the whole complex plane. This feature does carry over somewhat to the present case, but care has to be taken in order to take into account the whole hyperboloid surface, which is where the fault in the previous argument lies. Just because the hyperboloid is the surface that describes all 3-vectors of equal Minkowski length, doesn't mean that the properties of the hyperboloid is the same as the sphere's in Euclidean space.

Under Wick rotation:

$$\begin{align}
&t\rightarrow iz\\
&x^2+y^2+z^2=1 \rightarrow x^2+y^2-t^2=1 \\
&z=\sin\theta, \theta\in [-\frac{\pi}{2},\frac{\pi}{2}]\rightarrow t=-i\sin\theta=\sinh(-i\theta)=\sinh\lambda\\
&\cos\theta d\theta d\phi\rightarrow \cosh \lambda d\lambda d\phi
\end{align}$$

So far so good, but the fundamental difference between the surfaces of the sphere and the hyperboloid is that one of them is bounded and the other one isn't. The hyperboloid cannot be fully described if $\lambda\in [-\frac{\pi}{2},\frac{\pi}{2}]$. Instead we need  $\lambda\in\mathbb{R}$ to describe the whole surface. This leads to a divergent double integral for the surface area as predicted.

Here Wick rotating the coordinates is not enough to reproduce the result, because Wick rotation was not originally designed as a language/map to translate exactly between hyperbolic type and euclidean type of spaces. This is an example of how physicist tricks can fail miserably if applied outside their intended range of applicability, and is a lesson on how care should be taken about applying anything non-rigorous.